# How to sum up similar values of Map together

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, hashmap

I have this input below which presents a person at what age has what score.
And this is stored in a HashMap like this `Map<Person, Information>` the Person class has only `double: getScore()` which returns scores and the and the class Information has `int:getAge()` which returns ages. There is no attribute name in the class.

```java
   {Person has at Age: 12 (Score: 50)
=alex,
 Person has at Age: 16 (Score: 50)
=miki, 
Person has at Age: 5 (Score: 100)
=shi, 
Person has at Age: 4 (Score: 50)
=rafi, 
Person has at Age: 1 (Score: 50). (Score: 50)
=sharbel, 
Person has at Age: 5 (Score: 0). (Score: 0)
=thomas, 
Person has at Age: 14 (Score: 60). (Score: 60)
=thomy, 
Person has at Age: 14 (Score: 50). (Score: 50)
=angelos,
 Person has at Age: 11 (Score: 50). (Score: 50)
=musti, 
Person has at Age: 11 (Score: 100). (Score: 100)
=aloo,
 Person has at Age: 2 (Score: 50). (Score: 50)
=evi}
```

What I need is, to group the users with same age and highest score among them. The expected output should be like this:

```
{Person has at Age: 12 (Score: 50)
=alex,
 Person has at Age: 16 (Score: 50)
=miki, 
Person has at Age: 5 (Score: 100)
=[shi,thomas], // those are together
Person has at Age: 4 (Score: 50)
=rafi, 
Person has at Age: 1 (Score: 50)
=sharbel, 

Person has at Age: 14 (Score: 60).
=[thomy , angelos], // those are together and we consider the biggest score 60

 Person has at Age: 11 (Score: 100)
=[musti, aloo],  // those are together and we consider the biggest score 100
 Person has at Age: 2 (Score: 50)
=evi}
```

so note that `[thomy, angelos]` are together and `[musti, aloo]` are together this is because they have the same age and we consider the biggest score between them.

I tried many different ways but it was not successfully therefore I did not put any tried implementations.

Comment: Please correct this statement "What is need to get the hightest score of the persons which has the same edges and but its name together so the expected output should be like this".

Comment: You can iterate over the map for each age, calling ```getAge()``` for each person in the map and then getting the scores using ```getScore()```. Count the people who have the max score and put this in a ```List<Name>```.

Comment: @Kshitij could you please release your idea using java code?

Comment: Why age 5 persons are not in a group in your output section?

Comment: @jnrdn0011 updated, thanks i forgot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stream like this:

```
Map<Person, List<String>> result = origin.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().getAge())).entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                        .max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getScore))
                        .get(),
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        );
```

But I would suggest to use another way using simple classes instead of a complex Map.

**Outputs**

```
Person(score=50.0, age=1) - [sharbel]
Person(score=100.0, age=11) - [aloo, musti]
Person(score=50.0, age=12) - [alex]
Person(score=60.0, age=14) - [thomy, angelos]
Person(score=50.0, age=2) - [evi]
Person(score=100.0, age=5) - [shi, thomas]
Person(score=50.0, age=4) - [rafi]
Person(score=50.0, age=16) - [miki]
```

Comment: I am checking this solution, could you please see updated post? i released that the getAge() is in an object called information `Map<Person, Information>`. Could you please update your answer accordingly ?

Comment: @Catalina please ask a new question and I'm sure we will answer you, as it know here in stackoverflow, the question should have my subject if you want another one, then you can create a new post where you should to describe all the details of the problem

Comment: please I have this question which is really this post related. how can I improve your solution so that I get additionally to the name  its score together? like this `[thomy=60, angelos=50]`

Comment: @Catalina you want to store `thomy=60` as an Object or just as a String? In both cases, you can change the `.map(Map.Entry::getValue)` to be `.map(v -> /*Fill object with v.getValue() and e.getKey().getScore()*/)`

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321819/how-to-store-data-in-list-of-objects-of-object